# Selenium Python - File upload over Windows

Tags: python, windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Final task is to upload photos to site.

When i click on Upload photo - Window from Windows pops up and ask user to select pictures

[image]

I managed somehow to click on Upload and the window opens.

```
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/label/div/div[1]/div/div'))) #.click(    
    myElem.click()
    myElem.SendKeys("path")
except TimeoutException:
    errorDuringFill = True
```

Also tried with [pyWinAuto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [pyAutoIt](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoIt/)

Wasn't able to accomplish it.

Using:

```
webdriver.Firefox()
```

**Edit HTML:**

```
<div class="listing-editor__box-content">
   <input id="img-file-input" type="file" multiple="multiple" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" class="listing-editor__input-img-files" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
   <div class="btn btn--large btn--wide bg--dark-gray">
      <div class="d--fl jc--c ai--c">
         <i class="l-icon cloud m--r--2"></i>
         <div class="tc--white">UPLOAD PHOTOS</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="tc--lg">or drag them in</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share HTML of upload button

Comment: @Muzzamil added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below locator using `ID` instead `absolute xpath`

```
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'img-file-input')))    
    myElem.send_keys("path")
```

Comment: Muzzamil, one question more. Can i push multiple pictures like this ?

Comment: @ProgramerAnel  Yes you can

Comment: By calling this method multiple times i see. I thought in send keys put bunch of paths

Comment: @ProgramerAnel  ahhh i need to check it if some way with sendkey or JS

Comment: In java, it works like (“Path1 \n path2”). You can try in python with \n  between path of files , if you want to check.

Comment: @ProgramerAnel  you can accept it as answer if it solve your issue.

Comment: I can't because there is no option for me. I can only upvote

Comment: @ProgramerAnel    https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow

Comment: @Muzzamil may i use your assist here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59955049/selenium-python-duplicate-images

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the file to the `<input>` tag using `SendKeys`. No need to use *pywinauto*. You can do it as follows:

```
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/label/div/div[1]/div/div')))     
    myElem.click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id='img-file-input']').SendKeys("filePath")
except TimeoutException:
    errorDuringFill = True
```