# Selenium python duplicate images

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using python to upload images to control over selenium. It works perfect but for some reason it duplicate the images.

I.E - First image is uploaded
Upload as main picture is confirmed.
Second image is uploaded
Third images is uploaded + 2 image re uploaded etc ...

Using this code

```
for pair in pair_list:
    file = pathlib.Path(pair)
    if file.exists ():
        #HERE I RESIZE PHOTO
        basewidth = 580
        img = Image.open(pair)
        wpercent = (basewidth/float(img.size[0]))
        hsize = int((float(img.size[1])*float(wpercent)))
        img = img.resize((basewidth,hsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        newName = pair.replace('.jpg','_resized.jpg')
        img.save(newName, quality = 95) 
        pair = newName
        myImagesToDelete.append(pair)
        #END OF RESIZE
        #print('Uploading photo:' + pair)

        if firstpic == True:
            firstpic = False
            #ADD MAIN PICTURE
            try:
                myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'img-file-input')))    
                myElem.send_keys(pair)
            except TimeoutException:
                errorDuringFill = True
            time.sleep(5)
            print('First picture added ' + pair)
            #CONFIRM PICTURE
            try:
                myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/button[2]')))
                myElem.click()
            except TimeoutException:
                errorDuringFill = True
            print('First picture confirmed')
        else:
            #ADD OTHER PICTURES
            print('Adding it as other picture: ' + pair)
            try:
                myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'img-file-input')))  
                myElem.send_keys(pair)
            except TimeoutException:
                errorDuringFill = True
            #time.sleep(2)
```

Paths is good which i can see in log
Loops are good.
in total of 5 loops i have 8 images added.

Python log log as it shows:
[Python log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebnTa.png)

Screen after upload :
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyEmH.png)

GIF : [image]

Comment: You have have 5 files in pair_list? Is execution is execution is very fast? Can you try time.sleep(2) before send_keys in else block and let me know?

Comment: I still got the same. Somehow it push duplicate photo after 2 sec delay. You can watch edit GIF

Comment: Are you using chrome ? If yes then what is the version

Comment: @Muzzamil `driver = webdriver.Firefox() ` 72.0.2 x64

Comment: Your code is fine as it seems to me But i have checked chrome have one issue with elements have multiple attribute and your upload button has this attribute. For that workaround you can use \n between 2 files and you can upload all files in one time if you are not using remotedriver.  Another approach is , can you try time.sleep(10) just I want to check. If it works then we have to check any html attribute who make sure file is uploaded then we can go for 2nd file

Comment: @Muzzamil 10 sec sleep wouldn't fix this. When you say \n between how do you think it ?  `images_path = str(str(repr(images)).replace('\\\\','\\').replace('\'','')) images_path = images.replace(' ','\n')`

Comment: @Muzzamil the output is `Message: File not found: "C:\Users\t3cho\Desktop\IMAGES\4841-001.jpg"`

Comment: No My meant to say as you asked before for multiple image upload in one time. For it send_keys(“imagepath1” + \n + “imagePath2”)

Comment: That seems to be working. Can you post it as answer.

Comment: Sure I will do post

Comment: Done. You can accept it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For removing duplicate images, you can  upload all images at one time so all images will be uploaded as duplicate.

```
myElem.send_keys(“imagePath1” + \n + “imagePath2”)
```